# How to test that I configured Subversion Path Based Authorization in the right way?

Tags: svn, security, audit, apache

The problem is about security settings of the Subversion repository served trough the Apache web server.

I use the Path Based Authentication to protect some company information from external collaborators. I need something that tests that the authorization is given the people I want, i.e. I need to check that I hadn't make mistakes in the configuration.

There is a simple way to test this: simulate the access to the resource using username and password of users. But this method requires knowing password of users.

For example the following BASH script tests the authorization of each users on a specified path ($url). Note: the users-files.txt contains username and password of users in the form "username:password".

```
url="http://my.company.com/svn/repo1/private-data/"
while read line; do
  username="${line%:*}"
  password="${line#*:}"
  if wget --quiet --user="$username" --password="$password" -- "$url"; then
    echo -e "$username:\tgranted"
  else
    echo -e "$username:\tdenied"
  fi
done < users-list.txt
```

There is a way to make this check without knowing the passwords of the users but only the username? I'm root in the machine where HTTPD and Subversion runs. Does HTTPD provides some audit tool?

The authentication is configured in the following way:

```
<Location /svn/>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/svn/
   AuthType Basic
   AuthBasicProvider ldap
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   AuthLDAPURL ldap://127.0.0.1:389/ou=People,o=mycompany.com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)
   Require valid-user
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn/svn-access-file.conf
   Options Indexes
   SVNListParentPath on
</Location>
```

Comment: Almost the same question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819900

Answer (score 2):

If by "check", you mean look up what the definition is - then you can just inspect the security config files on the server (in particular what [the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) refers to as the "rules-file") to find out who is allowed what access to what paths.

If by "check" you mean test, as in validate the rules that the users are actually allowed in practice by connecting as them over HTTP - then no, you can't.  In your example you are trying to actually connect to Subversion as a given user(name).  If you were able to do this without the password this would make a mockery of the whole security system.