# How to test that test if a path is (or isn't) writable without writing nothing in it

Tags: svn, apache

Suppose you have the following subversion httpd server:

```
http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/<project-name>
```

Suppose you have complex authorization rules that specify who can read where and you have written them down in the `svn-access-file.conf` which contain the path-based authentication configuration.

Now suppose that you would test that the configuration file is correct (without modifying the history in subversion).
You can test that a location is readable by a user (e.g. alex) using something like

```
wget --user=alex --password=******* http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/location/that-should-readable-from-alex/
```

You can test that a location is not readable by a user (e.g. bob) using something like

```
wget --user=bob --password=******* http://svn.mycompany.com/svn/location/that-shouldnt-readable-from-bob/
```

How to test that the location is (or isn't) writable by a user?

How do that in automatized way?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to set up a replica (with `svnhotcopy`, `svnsync` or another way) and do the tests there.